# 3D Rendering from a remote process in Android

Tags: android, service, opengl-es, 3d

I have a question regarding 3D rendering in android.
Is this kind of setup-possible?

```
Activity (A) has SurfaceView (B).

Service (C) in a separate process wants to render to the SurfaceView (B) by calling OpenGL APIs.
```

Pseudo-code would be something like this: Inside Activity (A), it creates a SurfaceView as follows

```
(Inside Activity A)
B = new SurfaceView(...)
```

Somehow, the handle of SurfaceView is passed to service (C) (in the separate process) and let's say the handle is B_

```
(Inside Service C)
B_ = get_surface_view_from_Activity_A
```

And, Service C is drawing to B_

```
(Inside Service C)
eglMakeCurrent(..., B_)
glBegin(...)
...
glEnd(...)
eglSwapBuffer(..., B_)
```

Is such kind of configuration available?
If so, could you point me to some example codes or tutorials?

Comment: Hey @jaeyong have you managed to do this?